# SvelteKit Static adapter add '.html' to href when building for production

Tags: npm, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit with the static adapter.

How can I change an `<a href="/otherPage".../>` so that when I run `npm run build` I get an href with the .html extension added?

Because currently when I run *build* my links are without *.html* so my static server can't resolve the HTML. And when adding the *.html* extension to the link it fails during `npm run dev`.

It's sadly not possible to change the webserver config.

Searches on the web only pointed me to `export const trailingSlash = 'always';` but I don't see how that should help me.

Answer (score 1):

`trailingSlash` helps *if* [pre-rendering](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender) is enabled, by generating one `index.html` per route, which should be resolvable by the most incompetent of HTTP file servers.